# Why do many small planes allow flight control from either side?

Tags: flight-controls

[image: Cessna 182 cockpit]
([From Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Cessna_182D_Skylane_Cockpit.jpg#mw-jump-to-license))

Unless the plane is being used for training, what's the point of having flight controls on both sides? As far as I know, it's not common to have a copilot on planes like this (Cessna 182).

Comment: FWIW most aircraft have a procedure to remove the second set of controls when desired (like to fit cargo on that seat instead). As to why they come with dual controls by default despite being a single pilot operation well... I have a theory but good question.

Comment: @Ben what's your theory?

Comment: It's an awful lot of work to remove the second set of controls in between times it is being used for training, and for what purpose?  Just because a plane isn't dedicated 100% to training, or doesn't require a co-pilot doesn't mean two rated pilots might not want to share flight time...

Comment: Nearly all small planes are used for flight training, even if only intermittently; adding and removing the second set of controls each time is not worth the cost.

Comment: So that you can fly over Great Britain and Australia! ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Your Question:** *Unless the plane is being used for training, what's the point of having flight controls on both sides?*

In my experience a significant portion of the life-cycle of of a single-pilot certificated airplane involves "training" of some type. Designing and building a mass-marketed (single-pilot certificated) airplane, with only a single set of flight controls (yoke/rudder pedals), would greatly reduce its usefulness/utility considering the many types of operations under which U.S regulatory requirements mandate dual flight controls.

For example, dual controls (in the U.S.) are required for *(note some exceptions apply):*

1. General flight training for airplane pilot certificates and ratings;
2. Simulated instrument flight requiring a Safety Pilot;
3. Pilot Certification checks (taking a check ride for a PPL, CPL, Instrument rating, etc. - there is some Examiner discretion on requiring dual controls);
4. Passenger carrying IFR operations under [14 CFR Part 135.101](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-G/part-135/subpart-B/section-135.101), except as provided in 14 CFR 135.105 (e.g., having an autopilot);
5. A Flight Review;
6. High-Performance/Tailwheel/Complex Airplane/Pressurized Airplane training (some of this training can be completed in an appropriate simulator/flight training device);
7. Sometimes satisfying insurance requirements for "low-time in type" pilots while acquiring experience.

If you own an airplane and it has only a single set of controls you would have to rent another airplane with dual controls to accomplish those items listed above.  Additionally, there are likely thousands of airplanes used by 14 CFR Part 141 and  Part 61 schools that, with limited exception, require dual controls. The ability of the manufacturer or individual to sell an airplane with a single set of controls to a flight training facility would be extremely limited.

If an airplane with only a single set of controls is never operated in its entire life-cycle (consisting of many, many, years) in any of the training circumstances noted above, then dual controls may be unnecessary.

In my opinion, value, marketability, usefulness, and utility have gone into the manufacturer's decision to make mass-marketed single-pilot certificated airplanes with dual flight controls. There are limited exceptions to this (e.g., some Bonanzas), but those aircraft would typically have easily changeable single to dual or throwover yokes.

(Note: A relatively few airplanes have a "Throwover Control Wheel," which provides a reasonably similar flight control capability to dual controls and can be used under some circumstances.  See [14 CFR 91.109 (a)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-F/part-91/subpart-B#p-91.109(a))).

Comment: In the US, 91.109 Flight instruction; Simulated instrument flight and certain flight tests. applies to Instrument Flight Instruction, Flight Reviews and Safety pilots. Aileron and elevator controls are NOT required in both pilot positions.

Comment: @JScarry 91.109 (a) states in part: *No person may operate a civil aircraft...that is being used for flight instruction unless that aircraft has fully functioning dual controls. However, instrument flight instruction may be given in an airplane that is equipped with a single, functioning throwover control wheel that controls the elevator and ailerons, in place of fixed, dual controls*. See the note in my answer regarding "Throwover Control Wheels." Also, do you have a reference regarding "Flight Review" (61.56)?

Comment: Same section (b) allows throwover flight controls as you have noted.

Comment: @JScarry That's why I  included a reference to thowover flight controls in my answer.  There are relatively few aircraft that have throwover controls, the use of which is at the Instructor's discretion. Also, I think debate on throwover controls is beyond the point of the OP's question.